# How to display the date with the correct client timezone in Prestashop 1.7.7.2?

Tags: timezone, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a very unusual problem and I'm stuck for several days.

I implore your help :-).

When my Californian customers order on my Prestashop, time is the order confirmation emails is wrong.

All times are in the New York time zone (this one I selected for my store).

How can I ensure that my Californian customers have right timezone in their emails? Same thing for European customers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "time is the order confirmation emails" ?  

If you mean the datetime value inside the order_conf mail template, this is the mysql date_add value of ps_order table , so it's read "as is" from your database in YOUR timezone, so I don't know why you would like to edit it. Anyway you should override core to manipulate that value based on the customer order id_country before passing it in the e-mail order_conf template.

Comment: Note that `id_country` may suffice for some countries with a single timezone, countries with multiple timezones will need more handling perhaps based on state/province.

Comment: It would be simpler perhaps to include the server timezone in the order confirmation emails.

Comment: @user3256843 Thank you for your answers !

Yes I am talking about the datetime that is displayed in the order confirmation email.

Comment: @justin-ezequiel Thank you for your answers ! I could indicate the timezone in the email but I do not like this method :-) .

I prefer to use the customer's country (or state) to calculate the right timezone, but how to do it technically?

I must modify the controller which sends emails and place it in the overrides directory?

Thanks again for your help !